# How to obtain the causal graph of a problem in pddl using fast downward

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning, pddl

How can I get the causal graph of a problem when I have the PDDL of the domain and the PDDL of the problem, using fast downward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can obtain the causal diagram as an object in c++ as follows.

```
#include "task_utils/causal_graph.h"
#include "tasks/root_task.h"
...
TaskProxy task_proxy(*g_root_task);
causal_graph::CausalGraph cg(task_proxy);
```

If you want it as output, you can add these lines to the main file ("planner.cc"). In addition, you must move the dump(const TaskProxy &task_proxy) function in the task_utils/causal_graph.h file to public and use the following command.

```
cg.dump(task_proxy);
```

Hope, that helps ;).